# create mjpeg video from pictures in Android(Streaming from server)

Tags: android, video, streaming, video-streaming, ip-camera

I have server, that streams IP camera video(in this case my laptop is as IP camera). And stores JPG files that are accessible through internet. I have this code that should capture these JPG and make a video with them:

I am able only to get one frame and that it, program somehow does not refresh(frame refreshes if I rotate screen).

What I would like to know is:
1. If there is an easier way to reflect those jpeg pictures?
2. Why my program shows only one frame?

**Main Activity**

```
package de.mjpegsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import de.mjpegsample.MjpegView.MjpegInputStream;
import de.mjpegsample.MjpegView.MjpegView;

public class MjpegSample extends Activity {
    private MjpegView mv;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        //sample public cam
        String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/cam_1.jpg"; 

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mv = new MjpegView(this);
        setContentView(mv);        

        mv.setSource(MjpegInputStream.read(URL));
        mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
        mv.showFps(true);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mv.stopPlayback();
    }
}
```

**MjpegInputStream:**

```
package de.mjpegsample.MjpegView;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class MjpegInputStream extends DataInputStream {
    private final byte[] SOI_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8 };
    private final byte[] EOF_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD9 };
    private final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
    private final static int HEADER_MAX_LENGTH = 100;
    private final static int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 40000 + HEADER_MAX_LENGTH;
    private int mContentLength = -1;

    public static MjpegInputStream read(String url) {
        HttpResponse res;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();     
        try {
            res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url)));
            return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());              
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    public MjpegInputStream(InputStream in) { super(new BufferedInputStream(in, FRAME_MAX_LENGTH)); }

    private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
        int seqIndex = 0;
        byte c;
        for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
            c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte();
            if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
                seqIndex++;
                if(seqIndex == sequence.length) return i + 1;
            } else seqIndex = 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int getStartOfSequence(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
        int end = getEndOfSeqeunce(in, sequence);
        return (end < 0) ? (-1) : (end - sequence.length);
    }

    private int parseContentLength(byte[] headerBytes) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
        ByteArrayInputStream headerIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerBytes);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(headerIn);
        return Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH));
    }   

    public Bitmap readMjpegFrame() throws IOException {
        mark(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        int headerLen = getStartOfSequence(this, SOI_MARKER);
        reset();
        byte[] header = new byte[headerLen];
        readFully(header);
        try {
            mContentLength = parseContentLength(header);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
            mContentLength = getEndOfSeqeunce(this, EOF_MARKER); 
        }
        reset();
        byte[] frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
        skipBytes(headerLen);
        readFully(frameData);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData));
    }
}
```

**MjpegView**

```
package de.mjpegsample.MjpegView;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public final static int POSITION_UPPER_LEFT  = 9;
    public final static int POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT = 3;
    public final static int POSITION_LOWER_LEFT  = 12;
    public final static int POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT = 6;

    public final static int SIZE_STANDARD   = 1; 
    public final static int SIZE_BEST_FIT   = 4;
    public final static int SIZE_FULLSCREEN = 8;

    private MjpegViewThread thread;
    private MjpegInputStream mIn = null;    
    private boolean showFps = true;
    private boolean mRun = false;
    private boolean surfaceDone = false;    
    private Paint overlayPaint;
    private int overlayTextColor;
    private int overlayBackgroundColor;
    private int ovlPos;
    private int dispWidth;
    private int dispHeight;
    private int displayMode;

    public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
        private int frameCounter = 0;
        private long start;
        private Bitmap ovl;

        public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) { mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; }

        private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh) {
            int tempx;
            int tempy;
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD) {
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT) {
                float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
                bmw = dispWidth;
                bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
                if (bmh > dispHeight) {
                    bmh = dispHeight;
                    bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
                }
                tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
                tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
                return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
            }
            if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN) return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
            return null;
        }

        public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
            synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
                dispWidth = width;
                dispHeight = height;
            }
        }

        private Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text) {
            Rect b = new Rect();
            p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
            int bwidth  = b.width()+2;
            int bheight = b.height()+2;
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
            p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
            c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
            p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
            c.drawText(text, -b.left+1, (bheight/2)-((p.ascent()+p.descent())/2)+1, p);
            return bm;           
        }

        public void run() {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
            Bitmap bm;
            int width;
            int height;
            Rect destRect;
            Canvas c = null;
            Paint p = new Paint();
            String fps = "";
            while (mRun) {
                if(surfaceDone) {
                    try {
                        c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                            try {
                                bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                                destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
                                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                                if(showFps) {
                                    p.setXfermode(mode);
                                    if(ovl != null) {
                                        height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom-ovl.getHeight();
                                        width  = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right -ovl.getWidth();
                                        c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                    }
                                    p.setXfermode(null);
                                    frameCounter++;
                                    if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                        fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter)+"fps";
                                        frameCounter = 0; 
                                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                        ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {}
                        }
                    } finally { if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
        setFocusable(true);
        overlayPaint = new Paint();
        overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
        overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
        overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
        ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
        displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
        dispWidth = getWidth();
        dispHeight = getHeight();
    }

    public void startPlayback() { 
        if(mIn != null) {
            mRun = true;
            thread.start();         
        }
    }

    public void stopPlayback() { 
        mRun = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while(retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); init(context); }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) { thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h); }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
        surfaceDone = false; 
        stopPlayback(); 
    }

    public MjpegView(Context context) { super(context); init(context); }    
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { surfaceDone = true; }
    public void showFps(boolean b) { showFps = b; }
    public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source) { mIn = source; startPlayback();}
    public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p) { overlayPaint = p; }
    public void setOverlayTextColor(int c) { overlayTextColor = c; }
    public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c) { overlayBackgroundColor = c; }
    public void setOverlayPosition(int p) { ovlPos = p; }
    public void setDisplayMode(int s) { displayMode = s; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange... I changed  String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/cam_1.jpg"; to  String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/cam_1.cgi"; and it is working with a little bit of delay but that is ok.

So my last question still is unanswered: Is there a more simple way to reflect JPG's and make a MJPEG? Because this one takes a lot of codding to do :)